How to make a word UNDERLINE when whole text is in String in Flutter app?
I want to make the word Capital UNDERLINE here. How can we do that in String.
QuestionCategory(question: 'What is the Capital of India?', correctAnswer: 'Delhi'),


Can you brief here more. capital word is known to you ? or its dynamic ?

there are thousands of Questions where i've to make a word UNDERLINE in each Question. The word is not specified. for example in next question 'Who is the President of India?'. Here i have to UNDERLINE the word 'President'.

So for the word that UNDERLINED you have any model or API? like how you define that Capital is the word I want to UNDERLINE?

I think you can do it in two ways. First, you can use underline text generator websites to generate the underlined version of the word 'Capital' and paste it into your string.
String question = 'What is the C͟a͟p͟i͟t͟a͟l͟ of India?';

Second, you can use RichText. Split the string into multiple Text widgets and give the 'Capital' text a style with TextDecoration.underline.
RichText(
      text: const TextSpan(
    text: 'What is the ',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
          text: 'Capital',
          style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
      TextSpan(text: ' of India?')
    ],
  )),


The website link worked for me. You  can Bold, Italic, underline that text, without coding multiple line to underline a word.

You can use Text.rich or RichText for this:
Text.rich:
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'What is the ',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Capital ',
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'of India?'),
    ],
  ),
)

RichText:
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'What is the ',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Capital ',
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'of India?'),
    ],
  ),
)

